# How do I reference a sibling frame with Jquery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frames

Here's my main `index.html`:

```
<frameset cols="200,*" border="0" frameborder="0" framespacing="0">
    <frame name="nav" id="nav" src="nav.html" />
    <frame name="content" id="content" src="1.html" />
</frameset>
```

Here's `nav.html`:

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="1.html" target="content" id="test">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="2.html" target="content">2</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Here's `1.html`:

```
<body>    
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#content").ready(function() {
         $("#nav").contents().find('#test').html('selected');
    } );
</script>
</body>
```

What I want: When the right frame (1.html) loads, it changes something in the left frame (nav.html).

The syntax doesn't seem to work in the second line `($("#nav").contents()...)` because when I test it with `"#contents"` it doesn't work either, but does when I change it to `"this"`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to access the javascript object `window.parent.frames[0].document` or `[1]` to access your frame.

In jquery you can put this as a second parameter so:

```
$("#nav", window.parent.frames[0].document).find("#test").html("selected");
```

That is and only is when you are accessing the `window` object on the same domain.